# java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException Not authorized to access instance: book-server.appspot.com:book-server:books

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-sql

I have not changed my instance settings nor billing but now i can't get at my DB:
java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException Not authorized to access instance: 
book-server.appspot.com:book-server:books

What does this mean:
Authorized applications must be located in the same region as your Cloud SQL instance

I have checked my application settings and permissions, and my application ID is correct.
When I run from local development, the problem is not there.

Comment: What JDBC URL are you using to connect?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct instance id? You can find the instance id from the cloud console. Try using book-server:books.

Comment: hi. i am using:
jdbc:google:rdbms://book-server.appspot.com:book-server:books/books

Comment: seems to work with this url:
jdbc:google:rdbms://book-server:books/books
(suggested by sundaresan)